# Drag and drop keeps opening up the image in the tab

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create my own drag and drop for images, I thought that I had understood the tutorials that I did but it seems I might not have gotten it. So I was hoping someone here could maybe tell me if I did understand or not.

This is my html code

```
<div class="upload-console-drop" id="drop-zone"
    just drag and drop files here
</div>
```

This is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');

    dropZone.ondrop = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

So from what I understood is that by doing `e.preventDefault()` you stop the image from opening up in the tab when you drag it over, but in my case it still opens up.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to bind a preventDefault on event `dragover` too

Comment: I see now. I didn't realize that I needed to have the `dragover` as well. I thought that I could do that at a later stage. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also need to prevent dragover

```
dropZone.dragover = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```